# Pass parameter to jQuery code and back to controller from MVC 4 (Google Charts)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, google-visualization

The following code works but is hard-coded to a Guid (where it says "My Guid would be here").

VIEW

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        $.post('/office/GetDivisions', { id: "My Guid would be here" },
    function (data) {
    var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    tdata.addColumn('string', 'Stat');
    tdata.addColumn('number', 'Total');

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tdata.addRow([data[i].Name, data[i].Value]);
    }

    var options = {
        title: "Contracts"
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(tdata, options);
});

    }
// ]]></script>

@model CMIS.Models.Divisions

<h1>Division</h1>

<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div" style="width:300; height:300"></div>
```

CONTROLLER TO LOAD VIEW

```
public ActionResult Division(Guid id)
        {
            ViewBag.DivisionID = id; //the viewbag version
            return View();
        }
```

CONTROLLER METHOD CALLED BY JQUERY

```
public JsonResult GetDivisions(string id)
        {
            var myList = db.Database.SqlQuery<Dashboard>("EXEC [DBO].[uspDivisionDashboard2] {0}, {1}",
                Environment.UserName, id).ToArray();

            var data = myList.Select(x => new { Name = x.Stat, Value = x.Total }).ToArray();

            return Json(data);
        }
```

How can I replace the hard-coded Guid with something that comes from my controller?

I've passed a Guid to the model in various ways (Viewbag, a field) but haven't been able to replace that Guid string with this new source (Viewbag, a field) and have it work.

The use case here is that the user would see a grid listing Divisions and on clicking a link to one Division, I'd pass the DivisionID (in the query string for example) and show the Google chart for that Division.

MY FAILS

If I replace $.post('/office/GetDivisions', { id: "My Guid would be here" }, with $.post('/office/GetDivisions', { id: @ViewBag.DivisionID }, the controller code "GetDivision" is never executed.

Comment: Have you tried a hidden field?

Comment: Viewbag should be fine. You're just saying it isn't working; you need to show us some example of what you've done that didn't work.

Comment: I updated with one attempted solution

Comment: Have you tried using `$.post('/office/GetDivisions', { id: "@ViewBag.DivisionID" }`?

Comment: @elolos - that does trigger the method but the value of id is "System.Web.Mvc.SelectList"

Comment: Can you please add the controller code where you assign a value to `ViewBag.DivisionID`?

Comment: I see you've added the code for the action called by AJAX, but you should also add the code for the action that returns the view containing the reference to `Viewbag.DivisionID`.

Comment: Got sidetracked by coworker. I get "expected expression" from the VIEW at design time if I put the @Viewbag.DivisionID in there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$.post('/office/GetDivisions', { id: "@ViewBag.DivisionID" }` instead, the problem is that quotes are missing.

I would also suggest changing the `POST` request to `GET`, as you are only retrieving data and not for example creating a new resource. See [this post](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) for a brief description of both HTTP methods.

To do so, you need to change the code in `GetDivisions` from `return Json(data);` to `return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` because the default behaviour of MVC is to not allow `GET` requests by AJAX.

You should also make sure that the action is not decorated with the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Comment: Not sure why that didn't work the first time I added the double quotes but it does work now.  Thanks for the help!  BTW the "get" made the code stop working.